# How to hide appendix in table of contents in revtex4?

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

I would like to suppress the appendix sections in the table of content in a revtex4 document. I know that revtex4 package overwrites the standard commands related to toc. What shall I do in this case? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{revtex4}


\begin{document}

% Title page
\title{My Document}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

% Table of contents
\tableofcontents

% Sections and subsections
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction.

\subsection{Background}
This is the background.

\subsubsection{Details}
This is the subsubsection.

\section{Method}
This is the method.

% Appendix
\appendix
\section{Appendix}
This is the first appendix section.

\section{Another Appendix Section}
This is another appendix section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

a code example is above. and I would like to suppress the "A Appendix" and "B Another Appendix Section" in the table of contents. If possible, I want to replace them with an "Appendix" to represent all appendix sections

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: @JamesT Thanks! edited!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method of `revtex4` to ignore what's in the appendix. But with subsections it will fail.

I use `revtex4-2`, because `revtex4` is obsolete.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}


\begin{document}

% Title page
\title{My Document}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

% Table of contents
\tableofcontents

% Sections and subsections
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction.

\subsection{Background}
This is the background.

\subsubsection{Details}
This is the subsubsection.

\section{Method}
This is the method.

\subsection{Background}
This is the background.

\subsubsection{Details}
This is the subsubsection.

% Appendix
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tocdepth@munge}
\section{Appendix}
This is the first appendix section.

\section{Another Appendix Section}
This is another appendix section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, this works the same with `revtex4`.